# How to store iterative numbered values in a list?

Tags: r, list, function

I have iterative numbered values lambdaSample1_1, lambdaSample1_2, lambdaSample1_3.... lambdaSample1_1000.

## 1000 random Lambadas for dataset 3

for (i in 1:numSamples) {

```
# generate ramdomNumber for credible interval

randomNumber <- floor(runif(numSamples, min = 1, max = nrow(mcmcMatrix)))

assign(paste0("lambdaSample3_", i), mcmcMatrix[randomNumber[[i]], lambdas[[3]]])
                                           
}
```

I got lambdaSample3_1 ~ lambdaSample3_1000 from the Matrix that has 60000 rows by randomly selecting the values using randomnumbers from 1 ~ 1000.

Now what I like to do is to combine the generated values "lambda1_1" ~ "lambda1_1000" into a single list

I would like to store 1,000 values in one single list. Is there any way that I can write a simple code rather than writing 1,000 values into a list?

```
mylist <- list(lambdaSample1_1, lambdaSample1_2 ,,,,, lambdaSample1_1000)
```

for (i in 1:numSamples) {

```
# generate ramdomNumber for credible interval

randomNumber <- floor(runif(numSamples, min = 1, max = nrow(mcmcMatrix)))

assign(paste0("lambdaSample3_", i), mcmcMatrix[randomNumber[[i]], lambdas[[3]]])
                                           

}
```

how can I make this type of list without writing down 1000 times of lambdaSample1_x ??

Comment: How did you create these in the first place? They should have been created as 1000 elements of a list instead of 1000 objects. Can you do that instead?

Comment: Read about mget and ls, something like: `mget(ls(pattern = "^lamdaSample"))`

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  I suspect a better question is probably how to put the values in a list in the first place, not how to transfer them to a list after they've been created.  We need more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested code since your question is not reproducible, but something similar to

```
lamdaSamples1 <- lapply(
                    floor(runif(numSamples, min = 1, max = nrow(mcmcMatrix))),
                    function(x) mcmcMatrix[x, lambdas[[3]]]
                  )
```

Will avoid the problem entirely by adding your objects to a list in the first place.

`lapply` works by applying the function in its second argument to all values in its first agrument in turn.  Its return value is a list.

So, as a simple example, to obtain a list of the first three squares, we can write

```
lapply(1:3, function(x) x*x)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 9
```

Comment: Thank you SO much !! lapply family is still quite a bit scary to me but seems much more efficient than for loop! your code perfectly worked!!

Comment: I'm happy to have helped.  Please accept my answer to indicate to other users that your problem has been resolved.  `lapply` can be scary to start with, but it's really no different to a `for` loop.  The function takes the place of the body of the loop, the list of values defines the limits of the loop.  In fact, a good rule of thumb when using R is "if I'm thinking of using a `for` loop, there's probably a better way to do it".  There are exceptions, but not many...

Comment: thanks! i saved the answer and accepted! will try out the lapply fucntion more!

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist <- lapply(seq(1000), \(x) paste0("lambdaSample1_", x))
```

or

```
mylist <- list(paste0("lambdaSample1_", seq(1000)))
```

depending on what exactly you need. (It wasn't 100% clear to me - but one of those should do what you want.)

Comment: This gives a list of characters but not a list containing the objects from the environment, i.e. `list("lambdaSample1_1", "lambdaSample1_2", ...)` instead of `list(lambdaSample1_1, lambdaSample1_2, ...)`.

Comment: I *think* "lambdaSample1_<xxxx>" are the names of *objects*, not character constants, that OP wants to place in a list.  But I agree it's not clear from the question.

Comment: Thank you! it worked, but what i wanted was to bring the stored values for "lambdaSample1_x". How can I bring that values into the list??

Comment: @Limey I think you may be right. But then this question can not be answered in any useful way, since we do not know how the values are stored in OP's script. Either way using lapply to generate a list of values is (imo) still probably the best way to create a list from random objects - no matter if it is characters as shown or other values.

Comment: for (i in 1:numSamples) {
    
    # generate ramdomNumber for credible interval
    
    randomNumber <- floor(runif(numSamples, min = 1, max = nrow(mcmcMatrix)))
    
    assign(paste0("lambdaSample3_", i), mcmcMatrix[randomNumber[[i]], lambdas[[3]]])
                                               
    
    }

Comment: as @Limey says in a comment to your question - it depends on how you generate/load your values in the first place. creating a list after the fact may be more difficult than simply loading them into one from the beginning

Comment: I already stored lambdaSample1_1 ~ lambdaSample1_1000 values by using assing paste0 and now I want to combine them altogether in one single list

Comment: "I already stored lambdaSample1_1 ~ lambdaSample1_1000 values":  This is your *real* problem.  Store them in a list in the first place.  Don't create the list afterwards.  But how you create these values in the first place is something you haven't yet described.

Comment: please poste code in your question, not in the comments (especially not in the comments to an answer) - also if you want help, please explain your code as well as your problem in a bit more depth - and if possible show us a small reproducible sample

Comment: Ah I see. I should first store the results into a list! I wonder how I can store values into a list in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you have but you may try

```
x1 <- 1;x2 <- 2;x3 <- 3 # assuming these are already exist
xx <- paste0("x", c(1:3))


mylist <- lapply(xx,get)
names(mylist) <- xx
mylist

$x1
[1] 1

$x2
[1] 2

$x3
[1] 3
```

So you may try

```
mylist <- lapply(paste0("lambdaSample1_", c(1:1000)), get)
names(mylist) <- paste0("lambdaSample1_", c(1:1000)
```